# Track variable access pattern in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a program which accesses some functions in another class. I want to find out how often these functions are accessed and the values the variables inside the function take when they are accessed. 
I am doing it right now using a struct to keep track of the various parameters I want to capture. 
But is there anything in-built in Matlab that can do this? I want to capture this data, plot it and find out the model of access (Linear, exponential, etc..).

Comment: Tracking the variables in a simple struct does not sound so bad for a comparatively uncommon task. Are you experiencing any problems with this method or did you just ask it out of curiousity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the function access info you can use the built-in [profile](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html) function:

```
profile on;
my_program;
p = profile('info')
```

The output struct in `p`, i.e. `p.FunctionTable`, will give number of calls in functions and total running time.

Comment: Also, you can use it in UI mode.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will give it a try. I have used profile, but started it before I ran my program and stopped it after the program finished. I have not tried the p.FunctionTable.